# Using @Fetch(FetchMode.Join) in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes, Test2 and Test3. Test2 has an attribute test3 that is an instance of Test3. In other words, I have a unidirectional OneToOne association, with test2 having a reference to test3.

When I select Test2 from the db, I can see that a separate select is being made to get the details of the associated test3 class. This is the famous 1+N selects problem.

To fix this to use a single select, I am trying to use the fetch=join annotation, which I understand to be @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)

However, with fetch set to join, I still see separate selects. Here are the relevant portions of my setup..

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="max_fetch_depth">2</property>
```

Test2:

```
public class Test2 {
 @OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn (name="test3_id")
 @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
 public Test3 getTest3() {
  return test3;
}
```

NB I set the FetchType to EAGER out of desperation, even though it defaults to EAGER anyway for OneToOne mappings, but it made no difference.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I've pretty much given up on trying to use FetchMode.JOIN - can anyone confirm that they have got it to work ie produce a left outer join?
In the docs I see that "Usually, the mapping document is not used to customize fetching. Instead, we keep the default behavior, and override it for a particular transaction, using left join fetch in HQL"

If I do a left join fetch instead:

query = session.createQuery("from Test2 t2 left join fetch t2.test3");

then I do indeed get the results I want - ie a left outer join in the query.

Edit number 2:

Guys, thank you so much for your responses. Now I want to get to the bottom of this. I usually find that when I investigate something, I end up learning a lot more than I thought I would.

One thing I've learned already - I was running on old builds of hibernate because I didn't realize that the maven repository was out of date. Now I'm hooked up to the jboss repository too, and I have the latest versions of hibernate and hibernate annotations - 3.5.1-Final in both cases.

I've set up a small test case that simplifies it as much as I can - I'm still seeing the problem in 3.5.1-Final, tho' I'm 99% certain it's just something stupid I'm not setting up right, especially Ross, given that you got it to work (thanks for taking the time to try it by the way)

So I have these classes (full text this time)

Class A

```
package com.play.hibernate2;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
public class A {

    private Integer id;
    private B b;

    public A() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Class B

```
package com.play.hibernate2;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class B {

    private Integer id;

    public B() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

My whole hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property> -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play</property>
        <property name="connection.username">play</property>
        <property name="connection.password">play</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
        <!--
        <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

        <!-- I think this may fix my individual requests for OneToOne problem -->
        <property name="max_fetch_depth">2</property>
        <!-- <property name="default_batch_fetch_size">10</property> -->

    </session-factory>    

</hibernate-configuration>
```

The testing class

```
package com.play.hibernate2;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

public class RunTests4 {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RunTests4 d = new RunTests4();
        d.run3();
    }
    public void run3(){

        Session session = getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        createEntities(session);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("NOW WITH A NEW TRANSACTION");
        session = getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from A");
        List results = query.list();
        for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("Row "+i+" was:");
            A a = (A)results.get(i);
            System.out.println("Result "+i);
            System.out.println(a.toString());
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();


    }
    public void createEntities(Session session){
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            A a = new A();

            B b = new B();

            a.setB(b);

            session.save(a);

        }

    }
    public Session getSession(){
        if (sessionFactory == null){
            AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            config.addAnnotatedClass(A.class);
            config.addAnnotatedClass(B.class);
            config.configure();
            new SchemaExport(config).create(true,true);

            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        return session;
    }

}
```

And finally the log output showing the extra selects to get back the associated class

```
2 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.1-Final
23 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.1-Final
28 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
32 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
37 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
160 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
176 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
176 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
313 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
338 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
462 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.play.hibernate2.Test2
545 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.play.hibernate2.Test2 on table Test2
649 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.play.hibernate2.Test3
650 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.play.hibernate2.Test3 on table Test3
651 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.play.hibernate2.A
651 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.play.hibernate2.A on table A
653 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.play.hibernate2.B
653 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.play.hibernate2.B on table B
678 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
687 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Running hbm2ddl schema export
688 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - exporting generated schema to database
691 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
691 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
698 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
711 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play
711 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=play, password=****}

    alter table A 
        drop 
        foreign key FK412E010759

    alter table Test2 
        drop 
        foreign key FK4CF5DC04B7E1B79

    drop table if exists A

    drop table if exists B

    drop table if exists Test2

    drop table if exists Test3

    create table A (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        b_id integer,
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table B (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table Test2 (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(255),
        value integer not null,
        test3_id integer,
        primary key (id)
    )

    create table Test3 (
        id integer not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(255),
        value integer not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

    alter table A 
        add index FK412E010759 (b_id), 
        add constraint FK412E010759 
        foreign key (b_id) 
        references B (id)

    alter table Test2 
        add index FK4CF5DC04B7E1B79 (test3_id), 
        add constraint FK4CF5DC04B7E1B79 
        foreign key (test3_id) 
        references Test3 (id)
2562 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - schema export complete
2564 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play
2571 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
2575 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2575 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 1
2575 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
2575 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play
2575 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=play, password=****}
2622 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.1.30
2622 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.9 ( Revision: ${svn.Revision} )
2633 [main] INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2635 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader - Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2636 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory - No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 15
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Scrollable result sets: enabled
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
2638 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: enabled
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
2639 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2641 [main] INFO org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2641 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
2641 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
2641 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Second-level cache: enabled
2641 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Query cache: disabled
2644 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge
2644 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
2644 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
2644 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
2648 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Echoing all SQL to stdout
2648 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: enabled
2649 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
2649 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: pojo
2649 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
2649 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
2697 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
2796 [Finalizer] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - cleaning up connection pool: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/play
2929 [main] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.play.hibernate2.B
        */ insert 
        into
            B

        values
            ( )
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.play.hibernate2.A
        */ insert 
        into
            A
            (b_id) 
        values
            (?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.play.hibernate2.B
        */ insert 
        into
            B

        values
            ( )
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.play.hibernate2.A
        */ insert 
        into
            A
            (b_id) 
        values
            (?)
NOW WITH A NEW TRANSACTION
Hibernate: 
    /* 
from
    A */ select
        a0_.id as id2_,
        a0_.b_id as b2_2_ 
    from
        A a0_
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.play.hibernate2.B */ select
        b0_.id as id3_0_ 
    from
        B b0_ 
    where
        b0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    /* load com.play.hibernate2.B */ select
        b0_.id as id3_0_ 
    from
        B b0_ 
    where
        b0_.id=?
Row 0 was:
Result 0
com.play.hibernate2.A@351daa0e
Row 1 was:
Result 1
com.play.hibernate2.A@2e879860
```

Edit Number 3:

If I do things Ross' way, with a load, a left outer join gets created. If I do it with a list, separate selects are issued. Here's the relevant code. Only changing this reproduces the difference in behavior:

```
    /* generates the left outer join
    A a = (A)session.load(A.class,1);
    System.out.println(a.getId()+" = "+a.getB().getName());
    */

    // Creates separate selects for each object b associated with each a
    Query query = session.createQuery("from A");
    List results = query.list();
    A a = (A)results.get(0);
    System.out.println(a.getId()+" = "+a.getB().getName());
```

I guess it might be called a 'bug'. As I mentioned earlier, in the docs, they say it's 'usual' to specify the fetch mode in the HQL rather than in the mapping, which I'm thinking might mean that the HQL way has had more foot traffic to bed it down..?

(by the way I added an extra 'name' field to A and B otherwise hibernate optimizes the retrieve because it can get all of B just from the foreign key on A)

Comment: Just a thought: I see that your annotations are on the getter - is this the same way for all other members of Test2? If not, fixing it may resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes, they're all on the getters (but I have made this mistake in the past and it did break things..)

Comment: Sadly the iterate doesn't work - in fact it's worse! Now it does the initial select, which gives it the object ids, then it does a select for each associated object, but doing a left outer join through the associator table, rather than just going straight to the associatee - a more complicated separate select! (see my comment on your reply below) Oh well. I think it's going to HQL to be safe, which is maybe better since it's more explicit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I select Test2 from the db, I can see that a separate select is being made to get the details of the associated test3 class.

I'm very interested by the code of the other answer because that's what I'm seeing too when testing the code you're showing, it generates two selects for a `from Test2`.

I'm using the following dependencies:

- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile

> I set the FetchType to EAGER out of desperation, even though it defaults to EAGER anyway for OneToOne mappings, but it made no difference.

This has no impact if you use Hibernate annotations because the Hibernate annotations overrides the EJB3 fetching options. See [2.4.5.1. Lazy options and fetching modes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, Pascal :-) That's good to get some replication. I've simplified the test case above. I guess either there's an error in my setup that someone will spot, or there is something funny in hibernate in this situation, though not in the one that Ross presents.

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct, partly for testing out the problem (which Ross also did, and I'd mark his answer correct too if I could), but also because by replicating it, you prevented me from going insane :-)

Answer (score 18):

As a distillation:

@Fetch(JOIN) will be ignored if you use the Query interface (e.g.: session.createQuery()) but it will be properly used if you use the Criteria interface.

This is practically a bug in Hibernate which was never resolved. It is unfortunate because a lot of applications use the Query interface and cannot be migrated easily to the Criteria interface.

If you use the Query interface you always have to add JOIN FETCH statements into the HQL manually.

Comment: I was dying to know why this is happening and it was not mentioned anywhere.
Thank you sir. My company and myself owe you a big deal.

Comment: @EyadEbrahim actually documentation is clear about it: *"Represents an association fetching strategy. This is used together with the Criteria API to specify runtime fetching strategies. For HQL queries, use the FETCH keyword instead."*  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/FetchMode.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me wether I use Criteria API or JPQL. I use hibernate 4.2.15.

Answer (score 2):

I created a very simple application to test the scenario you are getting and your code should work (it is working for me). The only thing I have tried that will give me multiple select statements is setting max_fetch_depth to 0. If set to 2 (or not configured) I get the left outer join in my query. What version of hibernate are you using? I am using 3.4.0.GA.

EDIT:
Below is the simple application I used (with the same versions mentioned by Pascal):

cfg:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hibscribs</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- property name="max_fetch_depth">0</property--><!-- uncomment to see where 2 selects are used instead of join -->

        <mapping class="com.mydomain.bo.Person" />
        <mapping class="com.mydomain.bo.Phone" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Person entity -- kept it simple only have @OneToOne, adding JoinColumn, etc made no difference.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Phone phone;

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Phone getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }   
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="phone")
public class Phone {
    private Long id;
    private String number;

    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Simple test:

```
SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session sess = session.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

Phone phone = new Phone();
phone.setId(1L);
phone.setNumber("1234567");

Person person = new Person();
person.setId(1L);
person.setName("Bob");
person.setPhone(phone);

sess.save(person);

tx.commit(); 

sess = session.openSession();

//Person p1 = (Person)sess.load(Person.class,1L);
//System.out.println(p1.getPhone().getNumber());

// changed the above code to use the Criteria interface below: 
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(Person.class);
List<Person> results = criteria.list();
for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++){
  Person p = (Person)results.get(i);
  System.out.println(p.getPhone().getNumber());
}
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        phone_.id,
        phone_.number as number1_ 
    from
        phone phone_ 
    where
        phone_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        phone
        (number, id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        person
        (name, phone_id, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        person0_.id as id0_1_,
        person0_.name as name0_1_,
        person0_.phone_id as phone3_0_1_,
        phone1_.id as id1_0_,
        phone1_.number as number1_0_ 
    from
        person person0_ 
    left outer join
        phone phone1_ 
            on person0_.phone_id=phone1_.id 
    where
        person0_.id=?
1234567
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test this out, Ross. I really appreciate it.. I've pasted in the full code of a smaller test. I'd be really interested if it work OK in your setup. It doesn't work in mine, even under 3.5.1-Final, but it may be something in my code, so I've pasted all of it.. Thanks :-)

Comment: OK - we're on the track of this. If I do a load, as you do, I get the left outer join behavior. However, if I do list(), and then get the first object in the list, it does two selects - see my Edit Number 3 in the initial question

Comment: Yes I am getting same results as you. Instead of using list try using iterate -- I gave that a try and seemed to work

Comment: Thanks Ross. I'm not sure that iterate is a viable alternative: from the javadocs: "Entities returned as results are initialized on demand. The first SQL query returns identifiers only". That suggests that the 1+N scenario will still occur, just time-delayed when you go to use the objects, rather than when the initial call is made? As I understand it, list is not on-demand, but rather all in one go. I think the answer is just going to be a rather kludgy including of the joins in the HQL. Maybe it's better that it's explicit like this anyway..

Comment: I tried using the Criteria interface to get the list, instead of using hibernate query. It seemed to work. I will edit the above code for reference purposes.