# Add two different tables is a single criteria (join )

Tags: hibernate

The scenario is i want to select candidates from my sql where resume searchable =1  and there city = Annistion.  (resume searchable is in 1 table and city is in another table)

Code.

```
Criteria  crit = session.createCriteria(CandidateResumeInfo.class);
    Disjunction disc = Restrictions.disjunction(); 

crit.add(Restrictions.eq("resumeSearchable", 1));
            crit.add(Restrictions.gt("lastUpdateDate",employerLastLoginDate));
            crit.createCriteria("candidate")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("userid",1));




    //MatchedCvsAsyncDataProvider.setRowCount(count);
    crit.setFirstResult(start);
    crit.setMaxResults(length);
    List rsList = crit.list();
```

// At this line my program crashes (if i remove the above line which says    crit.createCriteria("candidate")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("userid",1)); //   this its work fine )

```
for(Iterator it=rsList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)

    {
        candidateResumeInfo = (CandidateResumeInfo)it.next();
        candidateResumeInfo.setRowCount(2);
        allCandidateResumeInfo.add(candidateResumeInfo);

    }
    //session.close();
    return allCandidateResumeInfo;
}
```

Here are my Two classes which i am joining

```
     @Entity

     @Table(name="candidateinfo")
     public class CandidateInfo implements java.io.Serializable {

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String city;
private String stateProvince;
private String zip;
private String country;
private String yearsOfExperience;
private String loginName;
private String password;
private String address;
private String emailAddress;
private int passwordResetQuestionId;
private String passwordResetAnswer;
private String middleName;

private String homeEveningPhone;
private String workDayPhone;
private boolean videoSubmited;
private boolean resumeSubmited;
private String cellPhone;
private String availability;
private String workStatus;

private String desiredSalary;
private String currentJobLevel;
private String currentJobTitle;
private String targetJobTitle;
private String alternateTargetJobTitle1;
private String alternateTargetJobTitle2;
private String targetJobType;
//private String eventType=null;

private String joinDate;
private String lastLoginDate;

@ManyToOne
       CandidateResumeInfo candidate;

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="userid")
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name="loginname")
public String getLoginName() {
    return loginName;
}

public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
    this.loginName = loginName;
}
@Column(name="password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
@Column(name="address")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

This is the other Class

```
      @Entity

      @Table(name="candidateresumeinfo")
      public class CandidateResumeInfo implements Serializable{

private int resumeId;
private int candidate_userId;
private String resumeFileLocation;
private int resumeSearchable;
private Date lastUpdateDate;
private String resumeTitle;
private String resumeText;
private String skills;
private int rowCount;

@Column(name="resumeSearchable")
public int isResumeSearchable() {
    return resumeSearchable;
}
public void setResumeSearchable(int resumeSearchable) {
    this.resumeSearchable = resumeSearchable;
}
@Id 
@GeneratedValue 
@Column(name="resumeid")
public int getResumeId() {
    return resumeId;
}

public void setResumeId(int resumeId) {
    this.resumeId = resumeId;
}
@Column(name="candidate_userid")
public int getCandidate_userId() {
    return candidate_userId;
}
public void setCandidate_userId(int candidate_userId) {
    this.candidate_userId = candidate_userId;
}
@Column(name="resumelocation")
public String getResumeFileLocation() {
    return resumeFileLocation;
}

public void setResumeFileLocation(String resumeFileLocation) {
    this.resumeFileLocation = resumeFileLocation;
}
/*
public boolean isResumeDisclosure() {
    return resumeSearchable;
}
public void setResumeDisclosure(boolean resumeDisclosure) {
    this.resumeSearchable = resumeDisclosure;
}*/

@Column(name="resumetitle")
public String getResumeTitle() {
    return resumeTitle;
}
public void setResumeTitle(String resumeTitle) {
    this.resumeTitle = resumeTitle;
}
@Column(name="resumetext")
public String getResumeText() {
    return resumeText;
}
public void setResumeText(String resumeText) {
    this.resumeText = resumeText;
}

public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate) {
    this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
}
@Column(name="lastUpdateDate")
public Date getLastUpdateDate() {
    return lastUpdateDate;
}
```

This is my Applicantioncontext.xml file

```
             <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
             default-lazy-init="true">

             <!-- Datasource for database connection -->
             <bean id="dataSource"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
              <property name="url"
           value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobsite" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
             <property name="password" value="" />
            </bean>

           <bean id="sessionFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
           <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
           <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
           <list> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.Employer</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.StatesProvinces</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.EmployerJobs</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateResumeInfo</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateSkills</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateInfo</value>

        </list> 
     </property>  
     </bean>
     <bean id ="ManagerJobs" class= "jobsite.persistence.MySQLRdbSpringHelper">
      < property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
      </bean>

       </beans>
```

Here is the Stack Trace
01:41:57,623  INFO SessionFactoryObjectFactory:105 - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
01:41:57,624 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:340 - instantiated session factory
01:41:57,625 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:426 - Checking 0 named HQL queries
01:41:57,626 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:446 - Checking 0 named SQL queries
01:41:57,626 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:411 - Finished creating instance of bean 'sessionFactory'
01:41:57,627 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:411 - Finished creating instance of bean 'ManagerJobs'
01:41:57,629 DEBUG SessionImpl:247 - opened session at timestamp: 13066477176
01:41:57,631 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:410 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
01:41:57,631 DEBUG ConnectionManager:444 - opening JDBC connection
01:41:57,632 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:163 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobsite]
01:41:57,667 DEBUG SQL:111 - select this_.lastLoginDate as y0_ from employerinfo this_ where this_.companyid=?
01:41:57,667 DEBUG SQL:111 - select this_.lastLoginDate as y0_ from employerinfo this_ where this_.companyid=?
01:41:57,669 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:426 - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
01:41:57,669 DEBUG Loader:1197 - result row: 
01:41:57,670 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:433 - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
01:41:57,670 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:418 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
01:41:57,671 DEBUG StatefulPersistenceContext:860 - initializing non-lazy collections
01:41:57,671 DEBUG ConnectionManager:325 - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!

Comment: you put some log snippet but not a single indication of error. What is the error? And please don't duplicate questions. Every question can be edited.

Comment: there is no error ,thats the issue,it just gives the exception.At the top i have mentioned                                                           List rsList = crit.list(); // At this line my program crashes..     (if i remove the above line which says crit.createCriteria("candidate") .add(Restrictions.eq("userid",1)); // this its work fine )

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate noob fetch join problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931936/hibernate-noob-fetch-join-problem)