# Hibernate @Fetch(Join) isn't being applied instead of separate SELECTs

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a `Domain` Entity with a `@ManyToOne` uni-directional relation to a `Country` Entity which I'd like to be eagerly loaded with a JOIN instead of separate selects. I thought about using `@Fetch`.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Domain {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "domain_id")
    private Long domainId;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Country country; 

    ...
}
```

I'm using `HQL` to query these entities.

But Hibernate doesn't apply the fetching strategy. I've tried with `@OneToOne` (which doesn't change anything in my design), but that also doesn't work. Here's a sample SQL output

```
Hibernate: select domain0_.domain_id as domain1_2_, domain0_.country as country2_, domain0_.name as name2_, domain0_.type as type2_ from domain domain0_ order by domain0_.name limit ?
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country1_1_0_, country0_.code as code1_0_, country0_.currency as currency1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country1_1_0_, country0_.code as code1_0_, country0_.currency as currency1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country1_1_0_, country0_.code as code1_0_, country0_.currency as currency1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country1_1_0_, country0_.code as code1_0_, country0_.currency as currency1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country1_1_0_, country0_.code as code1_0_, country0_.currency as currency1_0_, country0_.name as name1_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
```

I'm assuming something is preventing it from being applied. What is that?

Comment: This may be a Hibernate bug so old it has become a feature. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16614100/116639

Comment: @Tom I see. That's pretty lame. I added the `JOIN FETCH` in my HQL queries and it worked, but sooo many queries to change. If you want some credit, post an answer!

Comment: I'm afraid i have no desire to earn any reputation from this sorry situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was querying my `Domain` entities like

```
FROM Domain domain WHERE domain.type = :type
```

and this was causing Hibernate to query `Country` entity individually for each `Domain` returned.

Based on Tom Anderson's comment and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931936/hibernate-noob-fetch-join-problem/16614100#16614100), I made the change in my HQL to

```
FROM Domain domain JOIN FETCH domain.country WHERE domain.type = :type
```

This causes Hibernate to only use one big query with a join in it to retrieve `Domain` and `Country` together, instead of one query for all `Domain` entities and a `SELECT` to retrieve the `Country` for each of those.

With `Criteria`, it seems this isn't necessary. Only when you use HQL do you need to specify the `JOIN FETCH`.