# One to one mapping between existing table and new table in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, hibernate-4.x

I have two tables **user** and **authority** table which are **one-to-one** mapped over shared **Primarykey**.

Now I want to have a one(**user**) to many(**logdetail**) between existing user table and a new table logdetail.

**Basically this is what I want to achieve :**

**logdetail** will have a foreign key column which is a primary key in already existing **user** table, of course the cascading functionality between these two tables.

Is this possible using hibernate ? or I have to do it by SQL queries in the DB(**MySql**)?

If possible could you please give a simple example.Or please suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19378217/1844148 this link may help..!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for what I have been looking for here  :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3Bct8tkfcs