# FetchMode join makes no difference for ManyToMany relations in spring JPA repositories

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to do this:

```
//...
class Person {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Group> groups;
//...
}
```

it generates n+1 queries when I do `personRepository.findAll();` through a Spring JPA repository, just as if I didn't have any `@Fetch` set. (One query first to get all the persons, and then one query per person to fetch the groups).

Using `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` **works**, though! It only generates 2 queries. (One for all persons, and then one for the groups). So hibernate reacts to *some* fetch parameters, just not the `JOIN`.

I have also tried removing the `EAGER` fetching with no luck.

```
//...
class Person {
    @ManyToMany()
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<Group> groups;
//...
}
```

I am using Spring JPA, and this is the code for my repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

Does JOIN just not work through Spring JPA, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Matsemann... You still don't find my answer right?

Comment: @DarkHorse it was helpful, but my problem is still there

Comment: I think you should now write an HQL query with join fetch to get result in single query..

Answer (score 22):

Going through many forums and blogs to read for your problem (I guess you might have done that before posting it here) I too think that

> @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) will be ignored if you use the Query interface
>   (e.g.: session.createQuery()) but it will be properly used if you use
>   the Criteria interface.
>
> This is practically a bug in Hibernate which was never resolved. It is
>   unfortunate because a lot of applications use the Query interface and
>   cannot be migrated easily to the Criteria interface.
>
> If you use the Query interface you always have to add JOIN FETCH
>   statements into the HQL manually.

References
[Hibernate Forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2456562)
[Spring Forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/39271-how-to-force-join-on-jpa-eager-fetch)
[Similar Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931936/hibernate-noob-fetch-join-problem)

Answer (score 9):

I also couldn't get `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` to work when using JPA *(although it works fine when using the hibernate Criteria api)* and I also couldn't find any examples explaining why, but I can think of a few workarounds.

The most straightforward way to load the Groups eagerly, is to use JPQL:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String>{
  @Query(value = "select distinct p from Person p left join fetch p.groups")
  List<Person> getAllPersons();
}
```

As you are using spring-data-jpa, you could also load the Groups eagerly by using a `Specification`. (As of 1.4.x you can chain specs that return null).

```
final Specification<Person> fetchGroups = new Specification<Person>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        root.fetch("groups", JoinType.LEFT);
        query.distinct(true);
        return null;
    }
};
```

If neither of these is an option for you, your best bet is probably to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`.

Another option is to use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` in combination with `@BatchSize`. `@BatchSize` helps to solve the problem of the n+1 queries. By tweaking the batch size you can reduce the amount of queries executed to CEIL(n/batch_size)+1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person {
  @Id
  String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @BatchSize(size = 20)
  Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {
  @Id
  String name;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<>();
}

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String>{}
```

This mapping results in the following sql when you run `personRepository.findAll();` on a database containing 10 persons and `@BatchSize` set to 5.

```
Hibernate: 
select
    person0_.name as name1_ 
from
    persons person0_
Hibernate: 
select
    groups0_.persons_name as persons1_1_1_,
    groups0_.groups_name as groups2_1_,
    group1_.name as name0_0_ 
from
    persons_groups groups0_ 
inner join
    groups group1_ 
        on groups0_.groups_name=group1_.name 
where
    groups0_.persons_name in (
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )
Hibernate: 
select
    groups0_.persons_name as persons1_1_1_,
    groups0_.groups_name as groups2_1_,
    group1_.name as name0_0_ 
from
    persons_groups groups0_ 
inner join
    groups group1_ 
        on groups0_.groups_name=group1_.name 
where
    groups0_.persons_name in (
        ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    )
```

*Note that `@BatchSize` also works for collections mapped with `FetchType.LAZY`.*

Comment: @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) isn't the same as fetch = FetchType.EAGER. While it implies eager loading, it uses a join as the mechanism to get the associated data, which avoids the n+1 selects issue.

Comment: @WillieWheeler I updated my post as it was a little bit confusing. I said that _"FetchMode.JOIN **seems to behave** as FetchType.EAGER"_, but I didn't claim they are the same. FetchType.EAGER only implies eager fetching and it doesn't say anything about the actual fetching mode. I should have said that _"FetchMode.JOIN seems to behave as Fetchmode.SELECT in combination with FetchType.EAGER"_ (when using JPA)