# Hibernate single query for common table across children?

Tags: hibernate

I'm looking to have hibernate to execute a single query for something that currently it's executing multiple queries for. The scenario I have is a parent object defined using JPA/hibernate annotations:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="example")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Example implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "theId")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@BatchSize(size=1000)
private Set<ChildObjectOne> childrenOne = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "theId")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@BatchSize(size=1000)
private Set<ChildObjectTwo> childrenTwo = new LinkedHashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "theId")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@BatchSize(size=1000)
@MapKeyColumn(name="attribute_id")
private Map<String, TheAttribute> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

Each of the classes in the one-to-many mappings (ChildObjectOne and ChildObjectTwo in this example) have attributes mapped exactly like attributes are mapped in the above Example class

TheAttribute class is defined like

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@IdClass(TheAttributePK.class)
@Table(name="the_attribute")
public class TheAttribute implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "the_id", nullable = false)
private long theId;
@Id
@Column(name = "attribute_id", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String attributeId;
...
```

What I've been attempting to do is have hibernate execute a single query for all the attributes across all the child objects for any particular Example instance instead of executing a query for each child or children for an entity. This especially would be beneficial when batch loading many Example instances at once :

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM Example e where e.theId in (:ids)")
List<Example> findAllByExampleIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Is there a way to get this desired behaviour with hibernate using jpa or hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this issue here

[FetchMode join makes no difference for ManyToMany relations in spring JPA repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891789/fetchmode-join-makes-no-difference-for-manytomany-relations-in-spring-jpa-reposi)

You may use a join fetch in the hql query to acheive this.

Comment: Performance is an issue with that approach. I tried it last night for just the children (I couldn't get the children of the children to work) and found that the performance was degraded from the batchsize approach. The explain from mysql shows a 'using temporary' which might explain it - we have some very large tables - the attribute table for example is 711 million rows.