# JPA exception :: path expected for join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Getting QuerySyntaxException :path expected for join. 
I have defined the path in entities.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "datapoint_template_condition_action_map_details_map" )
@NamedQuery( name = "DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap d" )
public class DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "iddatapoint_template_condition_action_map_details_map" )
private int iddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap;

@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "creation_time" )
private Date creationTime;

@Column( name = "is_disabled" )
private boolean isDisabled;

private int sequence;

@Column( name = "user_id" )
private int userId;

@Column( name = "condition_action_map_details_id" )
private int conditionActionMapDetailId;

@Column( name = "datapoint_template_id" )
private int datapointTemplateId;

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn( name = "condition_action_map_details_id", insertable = false, updatable = false )
private ConditionActionMapDetail conditionActionMapDetail;

public DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap() {
}

public int getConditionActionMapDetailId() {
    return conditionActionMapDetailId;
}

public Date getCreationTime() {
    return creationTime;
}

public int getDatapointTemplateId() {
    return datapointTemplateId;
}

public int getIddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap() {
    return iddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap;
}

public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public boolean isDisabled() {
    return isDisabled;
}

public void setConditionActionMapDetailId(int conditionActionMapDetailId) {
    this.conditionActionMapDetailId = conditionActionMapDetailId;
}

public void setCreationTime(Date creationTime) {
    this.creationTime = creationTime;
}

public void setDatapointTemplateId(int datapointTemplateId) {
    this.datapointTemplateId = datapointTemplateId;
}

public void setDisabled(boolean isDisabled) {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
}

public void setIddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap(int iddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap) {
    this.iddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap = iddatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap;
}

public void setSequence(int sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public ConditionActionMapDetail getConditionActionMapDetail() {
    return conditionActionMapDetail;
}

public void setConditionActionMapDetail(ConditionActionMapDetail conditionActionMapDetail) {
    this.conditionActionMapDetail = conditionActionMapDetail;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "condition_action_map_details" )
@NamedQuery( name = "ConditionActionMapDetail.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM ConditionActionMapDetail c" )
public class ConditionActionMapDetail implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
@Column( name = "idcondition_action_map_details" )
private int idconditionActionMapDetails;

@Column( name = "condition_action_map_description" )
private String conditionActionMapDescription;

@Column( name = "condition_action_map_name" )
private String conditionActionMapName;

@Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
@Column( name = "creation_time" )
private Date creationTime;

@Column( name = "customer_id" )
private int customerId;

@Column( name = "user_id" )
private int userId;

@Column( name = "conditions_id" )
private int conditionId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="conditionActionMapDetail")
private List<ConditionActionMap> conditionActionMaps ;

public ConditionActionMapDetail() {
}

public String getConditionActionMapDescription() {
    return conditionActionMapDescription;
}

public String getConditionActionMapName() {
    return conditionActionMapName;
}

public int getConditionId() {
    return conditionId;
}

public Date getCreationTime() {
    return creationTime;
}

public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public int getIdconditionActionMapDetails() {
    return idconditionActionMapDetails;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setConditionActionMapDescription(String conditionActionMapDescription) {
    this.conditionActionMapDescription = conditionActionMapDescription;
}

public void setConditionActionMapName(String conditionActionMapName) {
    this.conditionActionMapName = conditionActionMapName;
}

public void setConditionId(int conditionId) {
    this.conditionId = conditionId;
}

public void setCreationTime(Date creationTime) {
    this.creationTime = creationTime;
}

public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public void setIdconditionActionMapDetails(int idconditionActionMapDetails) {
    this.idconditionActionMapDetails = idconditionActionMapDetails;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public List<ConditionActionMap> getConditionActionMaps() {
    return conditionActionMaps;
}

public void setConditionActionMaps(List<ConditionActionMap> conditionActionMaps) {
    this.conditionActionMaps = conditionActionMaps;
}
```

}

And in my repository class in spring i have

```
@Repository
public interface ActionRepository extends CrudRepository<Action, Integer> {

List<Action> findByCustomerId(int customerId);


@Query( "select camd.conditionActionMaps from DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap  dtcamdm  "
    + " join ConditionActionMapDetail camd "
    + " on dtcamdm.conditionActionMapDetail=camd.idconditionActionMapDetails "
    + " where dtcamdm.datapointTemplateId=:templateid and camd.conditionId=:conditionid" )
List<ConditionActionMap> findConditionActionMapForDatapointTemplateIdandConditionId(@Param( "templateid" ) int templateid,@Param( "conditionid" ) int conditionid);

// List<Action> findByActionData(String data);
// List<Action> findByActionTypeId(int typeId);
```

}

Every time i try to run i am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select camd.conditionActionMaps from com.vuelogix.collygo.data.entities.DatapointTemplateCo
nditionActionMapDetailsMap  dtcamdm   join ConditionActionMapDetail camd  on dtcamdm.conditionActionMapDetail=camd.idconditionActionMapDetails  where dtcamdm.datapointTemplateId=:t
emplateid and camd.conditionId=:conditionid]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 84 more
```

I have added the path in @ManytoOne as per the hibernate documentation.I have searched similar issues but couldn't solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change query to

```
@Query( "select camd.conditionActionMaps from DatapointTemplateConditionActionMapDetailsMap  dtcamdm  "
         + " join dtcamdm.conditionActionMapDetail camd "
         + " where dtcamdm.datapointTemplateId=:templateid and camd.conditionId=:conditionid" )
```

Comment: Is multiple join in hibernate a good option rather than iteration from serverside?

Comment: Generally, you can accomplish almost anything you need in HQL, and the code is cleaner when all is done in one place. If you need some data, you can use `join fetch` so everything you need is pulled in a single SQL query. Of course, if you have a multi-purpose query, where needed data depends on the caller, you can fetch only the minimum needed data in the query, and then the caller could initialize what he needs using `Hibernate.initialize(<some lazy relation)` (if the caller is inside of the transaction).

Comment: fetch = FetchType.LAZY is hard to implement when doing object mapping using dozer / mapstruct etc

Comment: join fetch will not work in many to many relationships in spring jpa repositories [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891789/fetchmode-join-makes-no-difference-for-manytomany-relations-in-spring-jpa-reposi]

Comment: I was thinking of using `join fetch` in HQL with `@Query` annotation, you can see in the [thread you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19061378/4074715) that it works.