# jpql select column from one table and order by from another table without native query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hi I would like to select column from one table while ordering from column of another table. Effect should be same as this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.marker_name FROM Marker m INNER JOIN Lease l ON m.marker_name = l.marker_name ORDER BY l.location
```

Table marker

```
╔═════════════╗
║ marker_name ║
╠═════════════╣
║ ABC         ║
╟─────────────╢
║ DEF         ║
╚═════════════╝
```

Table lease:

```
╔══════════╤═════════════╗
║ location │ marker_name ║
╠══════════╪═════════════╣
║ 01-01    │ ABC         ║
╟──────────┼─────────────╢
║ 01-02    │ DEF         ║
╟──────────┼─────────────╢
║ 01-01    │ GHI         ║
╟──────────┼─────────────╢
║ 01-02    │ JKL         ║
╚══════════╧═════════════╝
```

I tried with following JPA/Hibernate SQL but failed:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT m.markerName FROM Marker m INNER JOIN Lease l ON m.marker_name = l.marker_name ORDER BY l.location")
List<String> findDistinctMarkernameOrderByLocation();
```

Error:

```
Path expected for join! [SELECT DISTINCT l.markerName FROM Lease l INNER JOIN Marker m ON m.marker_name = l.marker_name ORDER BY l.location]
```

I am trying to avoid use of native query so just wonder if any JPQL will work.

Comment: Try the same approach described on below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234754/jpa-exception-path-expected-for-join

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA exception :: path expected for join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234754/jpa-exception-path-expected-for-join)

Comment: JPQL uses classes/fields, and you don't post what are the classes/fields. Can you see the problem with that ?