# How to apply fetching strategies to a many to many relation

Tags: hibernate

Can anyone please help me how to put fechMode join in xml configuration for many to many relation.

Comment: Can you include more information? Which version of hibernate are you using (yee, I didn't know somebody was still using the xml config)? What have you already tried or which documentation have you looked at?

Comment: You also might be interested in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891789/785663