# Hibernate join all fields

Tags: java, hibernate, join, many-to-one

I am using **Spring Data** + **Hibernate** and have an entity with several **@ManyToOne** fields. Every field is retrieved by hibernate with separate **select** query.

I've already tried **@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)**, but no use,

Example:

```
 @Entity
 public class MyEntity{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "A")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B")
    private B b;
}
```

Hibernate will perform 3 db trips for *MyEntity*, *A* and *B*.

Is there a way to retrieve my entity and all of its fields with single **select** where *A* and *B* will be **joined**.?

**Edit:**

Entities A and B defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class A{
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

Repository looks like this (Spring Data creates implementation):

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity , Long> {}
```

And code that loads entity is pretty simple too:

```
myEntityRepository.findAll();
```

**Edit 2:**

I've just written QueryDSL query and for it only 1 select was executed. I'm happy with that at least.

Comment: "FetchMode.JOIN" should get in single select. How are A, B entities defined?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to load the entity?

Comment: Interesting. Specifying the fetch mode should not even be required. Default for @ManyToOne is Eager and the default FetchMode for Eager is joined. As an experiment can you try marking the @ManyToOne(optional = false)

Comment: Added @ManyToOne(optional = false), result still the same. I can still see select requests without any joins for each entity. In each FROM clause exactly one table.

Comment: Well everything seems in order so I can't offer any anything else.  If Join was absolutely necessary then it would be possible I guess to override the findOne() and findAll() methods either by annotating the interface methods with @Query("") and specifying fetch join IN JPQL or by providing a Concrete implementation of the repository and using the criteria API. Similar problem is here with an answer up-voted 12 times, although seems no different to what you have done:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931936/hibernate-noob-fetch-join-problem. What happens if you do a findOne()?

Comment: @AlanHay, thanks for response. If I do a findOne() actually everything is retrieved in one select. After browsing link you provided I assume that it might be the issue with Spring Data retrieving collection?

Comment: Spring Data just delegates to Hibernate Session so probably just one of Hibernate's idiosyncrasies.